# Can I use ‘as’ in this way?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

I want to use ‘as’ in the sense of ‘in a way of.’

Does ‘he cut an apple with a toy as a knife’ make sense for me to express that a toy with which he cut an apple was used as a knife?

Comment: As has been pointed out, your exact phrasing is *slightly* unusual. Or perhaps more accurately, the intended *meaning* is slightly unusual - so it would help make it easier to understand if you replaced the general-purpose preposition ***with*** by a more specifically "purposeful" word such as ***using***. I think that by the same token, using ***for*** instead of ***as*** also helps make the intended meaning more transparent. Either or *both* of those changes can be introduced to improve legibility here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is certainly a correct use of "as", although it would be slightly clearer if you said:

> He cut an apple **using** a toy as a knife

This makes it clearer that the toy was *repurposed* as a knife.

Or, if he wasn't actually successful in doing so and you just mean to say that he carried out the action of cutting:

> He *tried to* cut an apple using a toy as a knife.